# Criar uma cópia de lista em Python de forma que sejam independentes

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista

Possuo a seguinte situação:

- Possuo a lista_1 com os seguintes valores [10,20,30,40]. Desejo criar uma cópia dessa lista, porém preciso que a lista_2 não se altere quando eu modificar algum valor da lista_1.
- Possuo o seguinte código abaixo, mas não está fazendo o que preciso.

---

```
lista_1 = [10,20,30,40]
lista_2 = lista_1[:]

print (lista_2)
```

---

Desde já grato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> A diferença entre cópia superficial e profunda só é relevante para objetos que contenham outros objetos, como listas ou instâncias de classes.

Para o caso especfico que apresentaste, a maneira como fizeste (*shallow copy*, cópia superficial) resulta bem e é o suficiente.

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/jhKTwB)

A maneira melhor de conseguires uma *deep copy* é:

```
import copy

lista_1 = [10,20,30,40]
lista_2 = copy.deepcopy(lista_1)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo. Mas, não é isso que preciso, pois quando eu altero a lista_1 a lista_2 também modifica. Preciso, que ao modificar a lista_1 a lista_2 não mude. Ou seja, listas desvinculadas.

Comment: Editei, @Danilo

Comment: Perfeito Miguel. Era isso que precisava.
Muito Obrigado.

Comment: De nada @Danilo